# I lose the values in a struct (c)

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define stock_dir "/Users/myname/prices/"
#define file_list "/Users/myname/trade/trade/nasdaq100_stock_list.txt"
#define look_back_period 3
#define num_stocks 103
#define days_of_data 21

int main()
{
    FILE *stocks, *stk;
    char stock[11], fullpath[50] = "\0", header[25];
    char line_of_data[40];
    char *sclose, *svol;
    int n = 0, i = 0;
    typedef struct daily_data {
        char  *date;
        float close;
        int vol;
    }data;
    
    sclose = (char*) malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    svol =  (char*) malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    
    data** day_data = (data**) malloc(num_stocks*sizeof(data*)  );
   
    if (day_data == NULL)
        {
        printf("day_data not allocated\n");
        exit(0);
        }

    for(i = 0; i < num_stocks; i++)
        if ((day_data[i] = (data*)malloc(days_of_data*sizeof(data))) == NULL)
        {
        printf("data[%d] not allocated\n", i);
        exit(0);
        }

    for(i = 0; i < num_stocks; i++)
      for(n = 0; n < days_of_data; n++)
       
          if ((day_data[i][n].date = (char*)malloc(20)) == NULL)
          {  printf("data[%d][%d] not allocated\n", i,n);
             exit(0);
          }

    /* ... code omitted ... */

    if ( (stocks = fopen(file_list, "r") )== NULL)
        printf("didn't open file list\n");
    i = 0;
 
    while (fgets(stock, sizeof(stock), stocks) != NULL)
    {
       printf("%s",stock);
       strcpy(fullpath,stock_dir);
        strcat(fullpath,stock);
        fullpath[strcspn(fullpath, "\n")] = 0;
        if ( (stk = fopen(fullpath, "r") )== NULL)
               printf("didn't open quote list\n");
        fgets(header,sizeof(header),stk);
        n=0;
        while(fgets(line_of_data, sizeof(line_of_data),stk) !=NULL)
            {
                fgets(line_of_data,sizeof(line_of_data),stk);
                day_data[i][n].date = strtok(line_of_data, ",");
                sclose = strtok(NULL,",");
                day_data[i][n].close = atof(sclose);
                svol = strtok(NULL, ",");
                day_data[i][n].vol = atoi(svol);;
                printf("%s %f %d\n",day_data[i][n].date,day_data[i][n].close,day_data[i][n].vol);
              n++;
            }
    
        fclose(stk);
        i++;
    }
             
   for (n = look_back_period - 1; n  < (days_of_data  - look_back_period); n++)
      printf("%d %s  %f %d\n",n, day_data[1][n].date, day_data[1][n].close, day_data[1][n].vol);
    
}
```

The print statement in the `while(fgets(line_of_data, sizeof(line_of_data),stk) !=NULL)` loop shows that everything went into the right place. But when I print values outside they're mostly wrong.  I'm supposed to add more details but I don't know what else to say. I lose the values in the struct when I leave the loop.

Comment: I'd suggest running the program using a debugger, using a sanitizer or trying to simplify the program or the input to see if you can spot what goes wrong. It is hard to reproduce the issue without the inputs.

Comment: You have `while(fgets(line_of_data, sizeof(line_of_data),stk) !=NULL)
            {
                fgets(line_of_data,sizeof(line_of_data),stk); … }` — that means you read one line in the loop condition, and then read (but don't check the success of reading) the next line and then process it.  The `fgets()` in the inner loop is almost certainly wrong — and should probably simply be deleted.  That may not be the whole problem, but it is a problem.

Comment: The main problem is that you're overwriting the data because you have, for example, `day_data[i][n].date = strtok(line_of_data, ",");` but when the next line is read, `line_of_data` is zapped to hold the new line.  You need to allocate storage for a copy of the value returned by `strtok()` — probably using `strdup()` and an error check.  Your error handling after `if ((stk = fopen(fullpath, "r")) == NULL)` is dangerous; you should have a continue or exit after the print operation so you don't attempt to use the null pointer.

Comment: It's late here but a quick check seems to show you're right. Back to this tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: You might provide some snippet of the data you process.

Comment: `day_data[i][n].date = (char*)malloc(20)` followed by `day_data[i][n].date = strtok...` is a memory leak. It was already mentioned that this is also reason for your problem.

Comment: I fixed the fgets which was just stupid on my part and put in second print statement. There is no problem in the loop, only when I exit do I lose the values.

Comment: I fixed the fgets which was just stupid on my part and put in second print statement. There is no problem in the loop, only when I exit do I lose the values. If everything is in the right place when I'm in the loop losing it when I exit the loop, what does memory leaks have to do with it?

Comment: while(fgets(line_of_data, sizeof(line_of_data),stk) != NULL)
        {day_data[i][n].date = strtok(line_of_data, ",");
         sclose = strtok(NULL,",");
         day_data[i][n].close = atof(sclose);
         svol = strtok(NULL, ",");
         day_data[i][n].vol = atoi(svol);
          printf("%d %s %f %d\n",n, day_data[i][n].date,day_data[i][n].close,day_data[i][n].vol);
          n++;
           if (n > 0)
                   printf("check %d %s  %f %d\n",n-1, day_data[i][n-1].date, day_data[i][n-1].close, day_data[i][n-1].vol);
         }

Comment: On the other hand, your fixed solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the same data again and again.

Take a look at your structure:

```
    typedef struct daily_data {
        char  *date;  ///< a pointer without own storage
        float close;
        int vol;
    }data;
```

while processing your file you read each line into `line_of_data`

```
while(fgets(line_of_data, sizeof(line_of_data),stk) !=NULL)
```

you tokenize the `line_data` and assign the pointer to `data->date`

```
day_data[i][n].date = strtok(line_of_data, ",");
```

What tokenize ([strtok reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)) does is inserting  terminators into your input string and returning the pointer to the start of the new part of your input. So no new memory is allocated at this point. the returned pointer points into your input string.

So effectively you assigning the local variable pointer to your data storage structure.

Additionally to this you lose the pointer to your initially allocated memory for the `date` pointer.

I would suggest you to remove the a priory allocation of `date` and allocate the required memory at the point you really know the required length or if you are sure, you know the maximum length, then you can just make the `date` member an array.

So you either have to allocate new memory and copy the tokenized data or if you made `date` a fixed size array, just copy the tokenized data.

on the first variant it would look like this

```
  char * tok = strtok(line_of_data, ",");
  day_data[i][n].date = malloc(strlen(tok)+1);
  strcpy(day_data[i][n].date, tok);
```

(+ remove the pre allocation of the `date` member)

or the second variant:

change `data` to

```
    typedef struct daily_data {
        char  date[20];
        float close;
        int vol;
    }data;
```

and the processing code looks like this:

```
  char * tok = strtok(line_of_data, ",");
  strcpy(day_data[i][n].date, tok);
```

(+ (of course) remove the pre allocation of the `date` member)

You also should in any case add error handling if the tokenized string exceeds the max length or the format of the lines does not match the expectation (missing delimiters, wrong/invalid number(formats), ...).

Comment: There is already memory allocated for `day_data[i][n].date` before reading the file. Allocating again causes a memory leak.

Comment: @Gerhardh Oh - I missed this. I correct this. but the current implementation also have this leak because it overwrites pointer. also how could the actual size of the data been known prior to processing the file. if it is known, then there is no point in using a pointer instead of a fixed sized array.

Comment: Yes, it was already there. But if you are improving it, you might improve it a bit further and not replicate this flaw. ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh Sure. you are totally right ;)  I haven't read through the whole thing, I just saw the assignment of the local data and at this point I have not expected an allocation may happened before. clearly my fault.

Comment: Don't take it as a fault. Maybe take it as chance for additional improvement. :)